# Syncing UserDefaults to iCloud using MKiCloudSync. Undefined symbols for architecture i386?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsuserdefaults, synchronization, icloud

I'm trying to use MKiCloudSync to sync my user defaults to iCloud, but am running across a problem that no one else seems to have experienced with this plugin.  Before the build runs I get an error saying undefined symbols for architecture i386.  I know this is a rather unspecific error, but does anyone have experience with MKiCloudSync or have any ideas on what the problem could be?  Am I missing a framework?  Thanks

[image: console]

Comment: could it be that MKiCloudSync doesn't support architecture i386?  i386 is the simulator right?

Comment: I'm also getting undefined symbols for armv7 when I try to run it on my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10415850/1092219.  .m file wasn't added to correctly