# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 after using singleton

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to use this code:

```
FacebookViewController *manager = [FacebookViewController sharedManager];
```

to call a shared manager with this in the .h

```
+ (FacebookViewController *) sharedManager;
```

I get this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FacebookViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ContactFBSViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you using any third party static libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that error when I used older Facebook iOS SDK in XCode 4.5.

When I updated Facebook SDK to 3.1 and used the new API, I no longer got that error.

Comment: I'm using the latest SDK, with the Facebook.h file

Comment: Then I am not sure. Check this answer if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10415850/1017099

Comment: I solvd the problem. It was something related to NSNotifications from a sample app