# Linking problems with a category on Scripting Bridge

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-category, scripting-bridge

I am trying to write a category over iTunesTrack with associated objects (an NSMutableDictionary and an NSNumber)

```
#import "iTunes.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface iTunesTrack (dictionary)
- (NSMutableDictionary*) getDictionary;
- (NSNumber*) getScan;
- (BOOL)scanTrack:(NSString *)equationString;
@end
```

This fails:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_iTunesTrack", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_iTunesTrack_$_dictionary in iTunesTrack+dictionary.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have double checked that the Scripting Bridge framework is added and that the iTunesTrack+dictionary.m file is attached to the target.  Could this be some error with combining Categories with Scripting Bridge?

---

Update:

If I replace iTunesTrack with SBObject, this works.  I have no idea why, though.

---

Update 2:

This problem is reproducible:

1. Create new project
2. Add Scripting Bridge Framework and the iTunes.h header file.
3. Create new category of iTunesTrack with an arbitrary name
4. Ensure that `iTunesTrack+name.h` imports `iTunes.h`
5. Build

I found [this page](http://blog.jameskyle.org/category/cocoa.html) which describes using NSProxy and NSCache to store iTunesTrack objects.  Would this be a better solution than trying to make a category?

Answer (score 1):

Scripting Bridge is quite a mess.

The class `iTunesTrack` is actually called `ITunesTrack` under the hood.
I think they were not quite consistent with the leading lowercase `i`.

This is why they changed it after a while, but probably did not want to do it in the header file, to not change their API.

I don't think there is a way to fix this.

You can, however, just create the category on `SBObject`.

```
// The interface can be declared as iTunesTrack
@interface iTunesTrack (Additions)
...
@end

// The category MUST be implemented on SBObject
@implementation SBObject (Additions)
...
@end
```

---

## Caution

Be aware that the category will be available on every `SBObject`, so make sure that all properties and methods have a unique interface.

Comment: NSAddict's answer pointed the way to do something I've always wanted: implement - (id)debugQuickLookObject; for SBObject classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a category on iTunesTrack (or ITunesTrack, or whatever it's called in your header) because that requires the class to exist at link time, and it doesn't: Scripting Bridge creates the target application's classes dynamically at runtime.  (And they have technically arbitrary names, which is why `-classForScriptingClass` exists.)  It's still possible to add a method to the generated class, but it means mucking about with the runtime, which is generally more trouble than it's worth.  Just put your category method on `SBObject` and try to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

NSAddict's answer pointed the way to do something I've always wanted: implementing debugQuickLookObject for SBObject types to make debugging easier. Here's the category that does iTunesTrack and iTunesArtwork.

```
//  SBObject+Extensions.h

@import ScriptingBridge;

@interface SBObject (Extensions)

- (id)debugQuickLookObject;

@end


//  SBObject+Extensions.m

#import "iTunes.h"

@implementation SBObject (Extensions)

- (id)debugQuickLookObject
{
    NSString *className = self.className;

    if ([className isEqualToString:@"ITunesTrack"])
    {
        return [self handleITunesTrack];
    }
    else if ([className isEqualToString:@"ITunesArtwork"])
    {
        return [self handleITunesArtwork];
    }

    return [self description];
}

- (NSString*)handleITunesTrack
{
    iTunesTrack *track = (iTunesTrack *)self;

    NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString new];

    [s appendFormat:@"Title:    %@\n", track.name];
    [s appendFormat:@"Artist:   %@\n", track.artist];
    [s appendFormat:@"Album:    %@\n", track.album];
    [s appendFormat:@"Duration: %f seconds\n", track.duration];

    return s;
}

- (NSImage*)handleITunesArtwork
{
    iTunesArtwork *artwork = (iTunesArtwork *)self;

    NSData *data   = [artwork rawData];
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    return image;
}

@end
```

Answer (score -2):

You may find the answer in this discussion: 
[linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation)

Also you can try to clean and then rebuild your project or go to Project -> Build Settings -> Valid Architectures and check whether there's all correct. Some of these advises may help you.

Comment: I've tried cleaning.  I also just tried making a brand new project with only the category, iTunes.h and Scripting Bridge added and it still fails.