# Linker command failed error for static library 'libiphone-exif.a'

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, static-libraries

I have downloaded a source code which was attached with my mail. There was a static library named 'libiphone-exif.a' which was not working & showing error. Then I downloaded that library from code.google.com & added it through 'Link Binary With Libraries' but now I cant build this & its showing the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/codemenmini2012-2/Downloads/iphone-exif-0-9/Release-    iphoneos/libiphone-exif.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/codemenmini2012-2/Downloads/iphone-exif-0-9/Release-iphoneos/libiphone-exif.a
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_EXFGPSLoc", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in PictureViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_EXFJpeg", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in PictureViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_EXFUtils", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in PictureViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_EXFraction", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in PictureViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Files have been added multiple times.

Comment: Check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation

Comment: See once whether you imported  `PictureViewController.m` instead of `PictureViewController.h`

Comment: It's showing that files are missing for architecture i386(simulator), run it on device it may run successfully on device.

Comment: Did u mean the static library?

Comment: But its not running in the device bro!

Comment: Did you import .m insted of .h?

Comment: The error comes when the .m files are not part of compile source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded library from below link, and in it I found two folders for library,
https://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/downloads/list

1) Release-iphoneos,

2) Release-simulator-iphonesimulator

so when you run it in simulator (i386 architecture) use .a file from Release-simulator-iphonesimulator folder and when you run it for device use .a file from Release-iphoneos.

Try to do this and let me know if you get any error.

Create universal library and try again,

- Open terminal
- Cd to your iphone-ex download folder
- lipo -arch i386 Release-simulator-iphonesimulator/libiphone-exif.a -arch armv6 Release-iphoneos/libiphone-exif.a -create -output libiphone-exif-universal.a

after that use libiphone-exif-universal.a in your project.

Comment: I did this bro, but same error again!

Comment: check edited comment.

Answer (score 0):

checkout you target->build setting -serch path is set the static path multiple