# Xcode 5- clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using xcode 5 for my mobile app project. I got this error when I try build the project.

```
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L\\\\\\\"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rmbp/apps/rmbp/iphone/native/WorklightSDK\\\\\\\"'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rmbp/apps/rmbp/iphone/native/WikitudeSDK'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rmbp/apps/rmbp/iphone/native/Frameworks"'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rmbp/apps/rmbp/iphone/native/WikitudeSDK'
    ld: framework not found sqlcipher
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L\\\\\\\"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rmbp/apps/rmbp/iphone/native/WorklightSDK\\\\\\\"'


ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rmbp/apps/rmbp/iphone/native/WikitudeSDK'


ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rmbp/apps/rmbp/iphone/native/Frameworks"'


ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rmbp/apps/rmbp/iphone/native/WikitudeSDK'


ld: framework not found sqlcipher


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why?

Comment: You probably moved or deleted the frameworks that the linker can't find.

Comment: possible duplicate of [linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation)

Comment: your framework not link properly

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This error is because of some missing libraries in your project.

Check in your `Build Phases` -> `Link Binary With Libraries`. Any of your framework may had been removed from there.

Add it and Clean and Build your project. It should work fine.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Is there any way to find out which library is missing? I get this message----

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm7s`

Comment: You will have to remove armv7s from your build settings-> Valid Architectures. Look at my this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494615/xcode-5-and-phonegap-linker-errors-on-building-for-device-but-not-for-simulator/22497592#22497592. You'll have to make small changes to it.

Answer (score 15):

There is another probability that you are using Cocoa Pods to install the library but not open the workspace (`*.xcworkspace`) file of the project after `pod install` was successfully executed.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day.

Comment: I am using Cocoa Pods, and the App target builds fine, but not the Testing one. What would you suggest in this case? I checked what libraries to link in the test target and added the only one in the App target, but still testing fails with this error. Using Xcode 8.3

Comment: Here's the way to use cocoa pods and test targets: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html