# MFSideMenu is not working in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfslidemenu

Hi i have followed this github page to add    MFSideMenu and its showing following error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFSideMenuContainerViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is my AppDelegate

```
- (ViewController *)demoController {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    ViewController *main = (ViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home"];

    return  main;
}

- (UINavigationController *)navigationController {
    return [[UINavigationController alloc]
            initWithRootViewController:[self demoController]];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    leftMenuController *leftMenuViewController = [[leftMenuController alloc] init];

    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                    containerWithCenterViewController:[self navigationController]
                                                    leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                    rightMenuViewController:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = container;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

[image]

Comment: chcek your .h and .m are correctly added in the target or not

Comment: my compile source looks like that attached screenshots

Comment: where is your mfide menu clas

Comment: try this its work for me    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    SideMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SideMenu"];
    // SideMenuViewController *rightMenuViewController = [[SideMenuViewController alloc] init];
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController containerWithCenterViewController:[self navigationController] leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController rightMenuViewController:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = container;

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036826/apple-mach-o-linker-error-on-xcode-6-0-1  if this can help, might be if you are facing some arch issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in AppDelegate.m it works for me in storyboard.

```
- (ViewController *)demoController {
    return [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
}

- (UINavigationController *)navigationController {
    return [[UINavigationController alloc]
            initWithRootViewController:[self demoController]];
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];
    UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftSideMenuViewController"];
     UIStoryboard *storyboard1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"second" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *left = [storyboard1 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightSideMenuViewController"];

    [container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];
    [container setLeftMenuViewController:left];
    [container setCenterViewController:navigationController];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

also take a new view controller in storyboard and mark it as initial view controller and give its class name as well as storyboard id as MFSideMenuContainerViewController.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this will occur when the code for BoxView is not being compiled into your target correctly.

[image]

You need to ensure that the **target** you're building has its corresponding box checked for your **MFSideMenuContainerViewController.m** implementation file.

A 'Clean and Build' never hurts, either.