# ld: library not found for -lc++ clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: swift, google-cloud-messaging

This showed when I am running the app with connected device:

```
Ld DerivedData/TestPods/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestPods.app/TestPods normal arm64
    cd /Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.3
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk -L/Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/DerivedData/TestPods/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/Pods/GGLInstanceID/Libraries -L/Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/Pods/Google/Libraries -L/Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/Pods/GoogleCloudMessaging/Libraries -F/Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/DerivedData/TestPods/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/DerivedData/TestPods/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire -F/Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/DerivedData/TestPods/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/JTFadingInfoView -F/Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/Pods/GoogleIPhoneUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks -filelist /Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/DerivedData/TestPods/Build/Intermediates/TestPods.build/Debug-iphoneos/TestPods.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TestPods.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.3 -dead_strip -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -ObjC -lGGLCloudMessaging -lGGLCore -lGGLInstanceIDLib -lGcmLib -lsqlite3 -lstdc++ -lz -framework AddressBook -framework Alamofire -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMotion -framework GoogleIPhoneUtilities -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework GoogleNetworkingUtilities -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleUtilities -framework JTFadingInfoView -framework MessageUI -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/DerivedData/TestPods/Build/Intermediates/TestPods.build/Debug-iphoneos/TestPods.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TestPods.swiftmodule -framework Pods_TestPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/DerivedData/TestPods/Build/Intermediates/TestPods.build/Debug-iphoneos/TestPods.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TestPods_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/tannaz/Developments/TestPods/DerivedData/TestPods/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestPods.app/TestPods

ld: library not found for -lc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Please format question and add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had this error because of some missing libraries in your project. Check  your **Build Phases** then **Link Binary With Libraries**. The linker can't find some frameworks that may be moved or deleted.

Add the missing libraries. Clean and Build your project.

Check these related tickets:

- [Xcode 5- clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326995/xcode-5-clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-inv)
- [Xcode 7: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623130/xcode-7-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-again)

> To solve this problem:
>
> 1. Go to your project setting page
> 2. Select your project (left side)
> 3. Click the "Build Settings" tab
> 4. Search "Bitcode"
> 5. Set "Enable Bitcode" to "No"

Hope this helps!