# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Apple Mach Linker error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
How can I solve this problem new.

[Error screen short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLVaK.png)ck.imgur.com/kcAlv.png

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your app by using Command + Shift + K.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether GTMSessionFetcher is linked to your project.

Check, maybe this answer will be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21327118/2069114