# How to fix error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I am new to objective-C, here I develop an iPhone application which contains both ***C++*** and ***Objective-C*** files using xcode 5.1. When I try to use the populated value of `mytoken` from `CommunicationHandler.m`  to `CallViewController.mm`. I get an error **"linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"**. I also try to initialize `mytoken` with `extern` but value cannot display at `UserToken` (CallViewController.mm)*. Please help me to solve my this problem, your help will be highly appreciated. 
The following are CommunicationHandler.m and CallViewController.mm files with its .h files.

**CommunicationHandler.m**

```
// CommunicationHandler.m
#import "CommunicationHandler.h"
...
@implementation CommunicationHandler
NSString* mytoken;
...
-(NSString*) getToken
{
    mytoken=try;
    return mytoken;
}
```

**CommunicationHandler.h**

```
//CommuniationHandler.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SecKeyWrapper.h"   

@interface CommunicationHandler : NSObject {
}
...
- (NSString *) getToken;
@end
```

**CallViewController.mm**

```
// CallViewController.mm
#import "CallViewController.h"
...
@implementation CallViewController
...
+(BOOL) makeAudioCallWithRemoteParty:(NSString *)remoteUri andSipStack:(NgnSipStack *)sipStack andtoken:(NSString *)UserToken{

    [sipStack addHeaderName:@"UserToken:" andValue:getToken]; 
    if(![NgnStringUtils isNullOrEmpty:remoteUri]){
        NgnAVSession* audioSession = [[NgnAVSession makeAudioCallWithRemoteParty: remoteUri
                                                                     andSipStack: [[NgnEngine sharedInstance].sipService getSipStack]] retain];
        if(audioSession){
            [idoubs2AppDelegate sharedInstance].audioCallController.sessionId = audioSession.id;
            [[idoubs2AppDelegate sharedInstance].tabBarController presentModalViewController: [idoubs2AppDelegate sharedInstance].audioCallController animated: YES];
            [audioSession release];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

**CallViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iOSNgnStack.h"
#import "CommunicationHandler.h"
extern NSString* mytoken;
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation)

Please check if your files are attached to your compiled app.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern 'C' {
#endif
   extern NSString* mytoken;
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

If your CallViewController.h header is only included in C++ or Objective-C++ files you can skip the ifdef.
 `