# Pods was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libPods.a' because its architectures 'XXX' didn't contain all required architectures

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, cocoapods

A friend updated Cocoapods in our project. When I pulled the latest stuff from git I got the following error:

```
Pods was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libPods.a' because its architectures 'x86_64' didn't contain all required architectures 'i386'
```

This results in

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-___PODLIBRARY____
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have searched around for hours now trying to find it. The most common fixes I've tried are..

- Deleted derived data
- Delete build data
- Delete pods, and reinstalled with 'pod install'
- Clean project
- All of the above at the same time
- Experimented with 'Build Active Architecture Only', both in our project and in Pod Project. Inserted armv7 and armv7s as hard code instead of $ variable
- Experimented with 'Architectures', both  in our project and in Pod Project. Inserted armv7 and armv7s as hard code instead of $ variable

We are aiming for iOS 8, iPhones.

My friend got it to work by combining the first 4 options, but I cannot.

Does anyone have any suggestions? We're supposed to release before christmas so production time is precious :D

Comment: did you solved this?

Comment: Similar question and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559621/project-pods-was-rejected-as-an-implicit-dependency-for-pods-framework-becau

Answer (score 125):

Try to set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO` for 'Pods' project and your app's target

Comment: What fixed this problem for me was precisely the opposite: 

"Build Active Architecture Only" set to "YES" 

both in main target and Pods target + Debug and Release

Answer (score 4):

For me, what worked was to change the CocoaPod project "Base SDK" to "Latest iOS".

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the project first on an iPhone 4s in simulator and after that it should work.

Answer (score 1):

What fixed this problem for me was precisely the opposite of the most voted answer:

"Build Active Architecture Only" set to "YES"

both in main target and Pods target + Debug and Release

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I had the "Build Active Architecture Only" parameter set to Yes for Debug mode. Changing it no No fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that your podfile targets the same iOS version your project targets:

For example, if you're targeting iOS 10.0 in your Xcode project your podfile should include platform :ios, '10.0' at the top, too.

[Per this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49425019/108859), which was the problem in my case.