# An error appeared when I run Xcode 7 with entity iphone (linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation))

Tags: ios, xcode7

I used google signIn in my App. "build success" with simulator but an error appeared when I run with iPhone.

error message is as below:

linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: this is the common error show your full error

Comment: ld: library not found for -lFMDB
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: above is what show in the program. Thanks.

Comment: [642:10523] Successfully configured [SignIn].
[642:10523] Failed to configure [].
[642:10523] Subspecs not present, so not configured [Analytics, AdMob, AppInvite, CloudMessaging, Maps].
[642:10523] Subspecs expected to be present [SignIn, Measurement].

Answer (score 0):

> ld: library not found for -lFMDB clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I was getting same error and I got it resolved [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28410910/4221299).

> Try to set ***Build Active Architecture Only*** to ***NO*** for 'Pods' project and
>   your app's target

Comment: This wouldn't help you to make a general build

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using  the **`.xcworkspace`** file

**Don't use** `.xcodeproj` file even if it run the app successfully on your device. It wouldn't help you to make a general build.

for more details
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28111728/348589