# Project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'Pods.framework' because its architectures didn't contain all required architectures

Tags: cocoapods, xcode8

Target 'AAA-Pods' for project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'Pods_AAA.framework' because its architectures 'x86_64' didn't contain all required architectures 'i386 x86_64'.

This appears as warning, then linker error appears.

Comment: This warning is also showing in Xcode 9.3 but maybe it is due to, my project code was created with old Xcode version.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Possible Solution:

1. Open Xcode project (cocoapods project) using .xc... file.
2. Select Pods project in the project navigator (blue icon on left).
3. Under Project, ensure Pods (blue icon) is selected.
4. Navigate to Build Settings.
5. Set Build Active Architectures Only = No (for both debug & release).
6. Optional: set base sdk to latest iOS (or select the preferred platform/version).

Note: This solution resolved this issue (warning and linker error) for me.

*Suggested resources:*

Github Project: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2053
Github Pull Request: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/1352

Comment: pod generation should set it to `No` by default. it get's me every time

Comment: This solution worked properly for me. Thanks a lot! :) This should be selected as the correct answer

Comment: It don't work for me. I create a discourse here https://forums.swift.org/t/no-such-module-popupdialog-on-swift3/14722/6

Comment: finally :D Thanks sir :)

Answer (score 29):

For future Googlers:
Also make sure that your podfile targets the same iOS version your project targets:

For example, if you're targeting iOS 10.0 in your Xcode project your podfile should include `platform :ios, '10.0'` at the top, too.

Comment: that was my problem. I changed the value in the Podfile file and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

On a very new project on Xcode 9.4.1, the issue was that my Podfile's deployment target was set to `platform :ios, '11.0'` while my project's iOS deployment target was set to 10.3.

This caused the generated Pods project to target iOS 11.0 (supported by only 64-bit devices on arm64 architecture), but since my main project targets 10.3 and includes armv7 devices, this doesn't work when archiving a Release build since a Release build also builds nonactive architectures by nature (unless you only support iOS 11 devices).

The fix then is to simply change the Podfile's deployment target to match your main project's, in my case it's `platform :ios, '10.3'`. Afterwards, run `pod update` and the Pods project should be regenerated. Launch Xcode, perform a clean and you should be able to run the archive process.

Comment: this answer saved my day

Comment: I owe you a beer on your next trip to Israel !

Comment: this one could have saved my day :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is a little old, however I spent 2 days fighting the same issue right after XCode updated to 9.4. What I found was in the `info.plist` under the key `required device capabilities` `armv7` was set when it should have been blank. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Note: the valid Architectures in the build settings of both the project and the Pod project need to match with armv7, armv7s and arm64

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently after **migrating to Xcode 10.1**.

Building with Debug config was working just fine, however archiving with Release config was generating this warning. 
And then archiving would fail, because in the main project all the **module imports** referring to Pods were failing.

Checking the **Build Settings** for the **Project** I realised that **iOS Deployment Target** was showing a different value for my Release config.
iOS 10.0, while my **Podfile** was set to `platform :ios, '11.0'`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which works for me.

1. Open up .xcodeproject (not .xcodeworkspace)
2. Find IOS Deployment Target
3. Choose the latest version you have(My latest version is 11.4)