# How can I get my iOS project to build for the right version?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have built an XCode iOS project in Swift which uses a Firebase Database and I am trying to test it on my iPhone. While I was implementing my project I did not realize that it was set up for the wrong version. My phone is iOS 10 and when I tried to deploy it there XCode told me it was the wrong version and that my project was set up to run on iOS 11. I could upgrade my phone to test it but I would rather my app worked with more versions than just iOS 11, and I assume the difference between iOS 10 and 11 can't be so big that my simple application would not run on iOS 10.

Simply switching the deployment target in the project settings does not fix the problem. Is there a way I can rebuild my project to a lower version as I'm almost positive that as long as FireBase works on 10 my app should as well?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Setting the Deployment Target to iOS 10 is the correct solution if you wish to support from iOS 10 and later. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: @rmaddy I am on 9.2 and get the following error: ld: warning: object file xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/Pods_GolfGames.framework/Pods_GolfGames(Pods-GolfGames-dummy.o)) was built for newer iOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing quite a bit of googling I had a combination of things going on. I am updating in case anyone else runs into this issue:

First I changed the deployment target in both the project and target settings as well as all of the pods settings to the iOS version I wanted.

Then I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559622/3527664

Next, I closed Xcode, ran a `pod update` and reloaded the project in Xcode as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50959249/3527664

Finally I followed these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49562731/3527664

Not sure what combination of things was the key but all I can say is that the three solutions together as well as some fiddling with Apple permissions and I had the app running on my phone.

Comment: Would be great to have a reasons (warnings and error messages) which you had to follow mentioned solutions and not stoping after you had applied (first solution) deployment target to the version which is lower or corresponds to your iPhone iOS. Additionally, It would be interesting to know your iPhone Model ( 32 bit or 64 bit architecture) and if you have set up base SDK in the project to the version 10.