# ionic app build fails with error 'linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

When attempting to build using `ionic run ios -lc` I am seeing the following error in terminal:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/emulator/xXxXxXx.app/xXxXxXx normal i386
(1 failure)
Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/xXxXxXx/Projects/xXxXxXx/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,xXxXxXx.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,xXxXxXx,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/xXxXxXx/Projects/xXxXxXx/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/xXxXxXx/Projects/xXxXxXx/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
Error: /Users/xXxXxXx/Projects/xXxXxXx/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

When attempting to build the same app in xCode I am seeing the error `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

- I've removed and added the ios platform
- I've updated ios-deploy
- I've updated ios-sim
- I've restarted Xcode
- I've restarted my machine Xcode is up to date
- I can build other projects successfully

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Xcode error `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` led me to [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation)

The second answer there suggests a check for multiple / duplicate .m files in the Xcode project Compile Resources:

> That can happen if the same .m file is referenced multiple times in your target's "Compile Sources" section in "Build Phases". Remove duplicate entries and you should be fine.

So I had a check in Xcode and there was indeed a duplicate call to a plugin resource.

After checking package.json I found **the same plugin was referenced in two ways (with two paths)**.

Removing one of the two plugins resolved the issue.

Comment: for me, it was ionic keyboard. I had two plugin of keyboard with different name space. Check your plugin and remove unwanted

Comment: No duplicate plugins, no duplicate entries in compile sources. If only XCode would say **which** symbols were duplicate. Which package.json are you referring to - do you mean ios.json?

Comment: ionic 1 has a `package.json` file

Comment: Take a look to this topic:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1/75771

Comment: please elaborate on what files we need to look for

Answer (score 11):

I found the solution on github

`the solution for me was open the .xcworkspace file insted of .xcodeproj located inside my '/platforms/ios' folder.`

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1240

Comment: This was the solution in my case, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the solution for my case was simply

```
cd platforms/ios
```

then:

```
pod install
```