# ionic app windows and iOS versions

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, iosdeployment

I'm working on an app using the `ionic framework`. I first made the app for `Windows` on `android` and then for `iOS` on `iPhone`.

I just copied and pasted `www` folder from `window` machine to `mac` machine. But iOS deployment is giving different errors every time.

Is it because of versions are different in both windows and mac?

find image below:

[image]

Errors are like:

1. [Error 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528762/ionic-app-build-fails-with-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v)
2. [Error 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546607/xcode-7-2-in-archive-getting-the-issue-cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-n)

I've tried everything, but It's not working for `iPhone`.

Comment: try to remove and reinstall iOS: `ionic platform remove ios` then `ionic platform add ios`

Comment: Already tried many times. Still no luck. I followed this article. http://outof.me/embedding-cordovalib-in-your-iosphonegap-app-project/  but I didn't help also.