# linker command code failed with exit 1

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

When I try to build, I keep coming up with this error message:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
>         -[PF_Twitter _getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
>     "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
>         -[PF_Twitter _getAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
>         -[PF_Twitter _getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: did you check this ?

[linker command code failed with exit 1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation

Comment: @iKrutarth yes I did. That is what made me realize that it was an issue with referencing my frameworks. It only happened after I started using the Google Maps SDK with cocoa pods. I have one library that's red - "libPods.a" I went back and checked on Parse, and I have all of the needed frameworks as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is so late to answer... but i find the solution for this... may be it help someone who search for the same issue.....

So many different problems for the same error message.(`Linker command failed with exit code 1`)

**1)** if you had two `same constants` in `different classes` then also this issue happens.

**2)** if you have accidently imported a `.m file` instead of `.h file` in an implementation file.

**3)** This error can also be occurred if you have imported two different versions of same library ,in this case just remove the older version and keep only one version.

**4)** Adding the "`other linker flags`" in "`Project`" and not in "`Targets`". So, you move it to "`Targets`", it shouldn't be in "`Project`".

**5)** Check it out in **project->target->build settings-> search enable bitcode->set NO** in DEBUG

check out this .. if it's OK then once do like following.

**Menu > Product > Clean** ... then Run the project

Hope it helps you.. :)