# Xcode linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I ask for help for this error in Xcode:

```
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Ld: library not found for -lPods-Audioplayer
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image: xcode]

[image: library]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation)

Comment: Are you sure that the missed library (Pods-Audioplayer) does exist (in the search path)?

Comment: @Matthias  here is a picture of Frameworks

Comment: The red color usually indicates a missing file.

Comment: @Matthias then you say that the library is missing

Comment: I reinstalling the library and into the project even if the library is in red and I could make it go for the moment 

Comment: Are you opening the .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace file?

Comment: @iVapp did the answer below work?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are trying to run from the `.xcworkspace` file and not the `.xcodeproj` file - the `.xcworkspace` file automatically compiles all of your dependencies for you and still runs the correct scheme for your app.

Answer (score 0):

In some case if you manually link the framework to your project and failed when you build, you can try deleting and linking it again in your Build Phase/Link project with libraries.

Met the similar situation when I always fail the first time opening the project and building, but re-linking it makes the projects be able to build again.