# Framework Firebase not found Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to add all the frameworks that I need to use the Firebase, but I have a trouble with one framework exactly the FirebaseSimpleLogin.framework, the compiler says that can't found it but it's added. it's my first round with using external frameworks and this is new for me and I can't figured out what is wrong with this.

[image]

Comment: That's and old framework and not needed. If you follow the getting started instructions on the Firebase website, it will get you set up and going. Using Cocoapods make it s a snap. See here [Installation and Setup](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/setup.html).  There's a link for manual setup as well, but, stick with Cocoapods installation as it will get your project Firebase-ing in no time.

Comment: yeah this can be many things. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation this is the question that refers to that error specifically. Possible duplicate?

Comment: Thanks! I solved this using Cococapods it's much better to don't get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jay mentioned in his comment, you're using an old version of the Firebase SDK.

[See this quick video for setting up your project with the latest version of Firebase using CocoaPods.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=009UrLVlAbo)

Comment: Thanks!, it worked, at least I could finish my own chat with multiple users using Firebase