# Linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode

[screenshot of issue (orange lines are to cover up the Mac user name)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOZAT.jpg)

Please answer this question in basic english if possible, since I am new to this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation This is a duplicate question BTW

Comment: your issue shall be resolved on the link above

Comment: Most commonly : Duplicated a name of some variable, added a .m instead of .h, or pods/files were added incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

If any file or image might be added to your project multiple times then this error does come. 
So I suggest you check all files in your project once and delete multiple files.