# Project cannot find pods "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

It seems as if my project cannot find my pod files this is the error I am getting "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation?rq=1

Comment: If you want more information/help, you need to provide more information. What have you tried to fix it? Have you looked for similar problems? In essence, can you more thoroughly describe the situation?

Comment: this is all that I know about this issue. But yes,  I have changed multiple things in build settings that people say. But no luck