# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) - Pushwoosh Integration using Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, pushwoosh

I am trying to integrate 'Pushwoosh in my iOS app using Xcode 6.2 , but after adding the 'Pushwoosh.framework' , I received this error (I added the framework only once)

[image]

Do you know what I should do to fix this?

Comment: No one can help if you don't provide more details about the error. What are the duplicate symbols and where do you get them?

Comment: @rmaddy I have added the error list

Comment: Probably looking at the same issue for a different library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation may help you. It is mostly the problem of duplicate entries of these files in your project. Perhaps one with the code and one with the PODs.

Comment: @NeverHopeless Thanks for your reply. Actually I didn't added PODs

Comment: it is not necessary that duplication only happens in case of Pods.  Find files listed in error inside project navigator to see how many times they are included. It should be once. for example find 'pwappopenrequest' first