# Fabric + Crashlytics for iOS

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Recently I try to add Fabric & Crashlytics to my projects, but I got one link issue.

My base SDK is iOS7.0 and deployment target is 7.0 too, try to use the Fabric app for mac or cocoapods to add these frameworks, but always got error msg like this:
[image]

Anyone can assist? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: try to integrate with cocoapods

Comment: @M.K. yes already tried, but same issue. It only worked when change the base sdk and deployment target to iOS8.0 and above..But document says minimum support os version is iOS 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reply from Mattie, Twitter Staff

Yes. It turns out that Crashlytics does not support building with a base SDK older than "latest" for any given Xcode release. It's extremely hard for us to maintain build compatibility with older SDKs, even if we can maintain runtime compatibility.

So I need change the base SDK to latest one and revamp my codes..

Answer (score 1):

Add the run script provided by fabric to you. The [follwing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUFFK.png) screenshot demonstrates where to add the runscript.

Comment: Already did whatever fabric mentioned, pod install or drag the framework files and add run script etc. 
I also just create a totally new project and add fabric and crashlytics with same base sdk and deployment target, same error msg...

Comment: have you tried these solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation

Comment: I think they are different, the error in that link is "duplicate symbol", my error is framework can't be found, and WebKit is even unavailable to be added