# ld: 57 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, duplicates, automatic-ref-counting, x86-64

I'm unable to run the project. There is an error called "duplicate symbol _node in", I've done some research work to solve this error but it hard luck. I can not solved this..

Can anyone give some solution.

Below is the error :

```
duplicate symbol _mesh_devices in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _G_kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _mytimer in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/key_server.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/slvs.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/slvs.o
duplicate symbol _gbl_idx in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/slvs.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/config_name.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainView in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainView-EC7177132CB70655.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainView-9D4A89D1DDDB640.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainView in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainView-EC7177132CB70655.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainView-9D4A89D1DDDB640.o
duplicate symbol _gbl_idx in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/slvs.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckpnx148e.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckpnx148e.o
duplicate symbol _gbl_idx in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/slvs.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/kpKeySwitch.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/kpKeySwitch.o
duplicate symbol _ipFobSnd in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckpnx148e.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/kpKeySwitch.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyLauncherViewController.o
duplicate symbol _gbl_idx in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/slvs.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw_config.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw_config.o
duplicate symbol _ipFobSnd in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckpnx148e.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw_config.o
duplicate symbol _gbl_idx in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/slvs.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_switch.o
duplicate symbol _kvs in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw_config.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_switch.o
duplicate symbol _mytimer in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/key_server.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_switch.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_switch.o
duplicate symbol _ipFobSnd in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckpnx148e.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_switch.o
duplicate symbol _mesh_devices in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RootViewController.o
duplicate symbol _G_kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RootViewController.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RootViewController.o
duplicate symbol _gbl_idx in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/slvs.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_thermostat.o
duplicate symbol _kvs in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw_config.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_thermostat.o
duplicate symbol _nodes in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_switch.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_thermostat.o
duplicate symbol _mytimer in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/key_server.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_thermostat.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_thermostat.o
duplicate symbol _node in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_switch.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_thermostat.o
duplicate symbol _ipFobSnd in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckpnx148e.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_thermostat.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/IPDWebLauncherViewController.o
duplicate symbol _kvs in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw_config.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/splashViewController.o
duplicate symbol _mesh_devices in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol _G_kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyLauncherView.o
duplicate symbol _gbl_idx in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/slvs.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckp6160.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckp6160.o
duplicate symbol _ipFobSnd in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckpnx148e.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckp6160.o
duplicate symbol _zn_at_idx in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw_config.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw.o
duplicate symbol _gbl_idx in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/slvs.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw.o
duplicate symbol _zn_list in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw_config.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw.o
duplicate symbol _kvs in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw_config.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw.o
duplicate symbol _ipFobSnd in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckpnx148e.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw.o
duplicate symbol _last_entity_lauched in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw_config.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw.o
duplicate symbol _gbl_idx in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/slvs.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckppk5500.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckppk5500.o
duplicate symbol _ipFobSnd in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckpnx148e.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vckppk5500.o
duplicate symbol _kvp in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RootViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/config_settings.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/config_settings.o
duplicate symbol _gbl_idx in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/slvs.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_lock.o
duplicate symbol _kvs in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/zgw_config.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_lock.o
duplicate symbol _nodes in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_switch.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_lock.o
duplicate symbol _kConn in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventLogViewController.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_lock.o
duplicate symbol _node in:
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_switch.o
     build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ipFob.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ha_lock.o
ld: 57 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation)

Comment: You might have imported the .m instead of the .h file

Comment: @PiyushPatel I've imported .h file

Answer (score 0):

delete the derived data from xcode preference and check once again duplicate file there in your project navigator

Answer (score 0):

Based on your duplicate error there may be 2 or 3 cases can raise this error.

**1st.** Either you have declare same global variable in 2 or more different classes like in your case you have duplicate symbol in

```
EventLogViewController & RootViewController & MyLauncherViewController
```

and variable suspect here in that class are :

```
_kConn & _gbl_idx
```

please check that not declare at multiple classes as global variable.

**2nd.** May be by mistake you have imported **.m** file any where.

**3rd.** May be you have added same classes twice in your project at different different folder please search one of above duplicate controller may be you can find twice in your project.

Hope this will help to solve your duplicate symbol issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two ViewControllers which are both using identically named variable or object? For example, UITableView *tableView or int yourInt on both ViewControllers?